# Local docusaurus plugins in typescript

Tags: docusaurus

I want to write local docusaurus plugins using typescript. (it works fine using js)

Is this possible? Like the [docs here](https://docusaurus.io/docs/using-plugins) suggest to put them under `./src/plugins/name-of-plugin`.

Reading the [docs](https://docusaurus.io/docs/api/plugin-methods) there are examples with ts, but if I just try and replace is with ts i get various errors. (eg "Cannot find module").

I'm using typescript for pages as well.

Comment: Could you provide a link to a repro giving the "Cannot find module" error.

Comment: Not at the moment unfortunately. Is it suppose to "just work"?

Comment: Could you copy-paste the error into the question, as the stack trace and all could help understand it?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the file extension worked for me.
For example:

```
plugins: ['./src/plugins/my-plugin.ts'],
```

my-plugin.ts

```
module.exports = async function myPlugin(context, options) {
  return {
    name: "my-plugin",
    async loadContent() {
      console.log("Hello World plugin wow!");
    },
    async contentLoaded({ content, actions }) {
      console.log(content);
    },
  };
};
```

removing the extension shows the same error :)

Comment: That doesn't work if I'm importing packages. Then i get "Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Comment: Do you mean if you're importing packages inside of the plugin itself?